# how to split & replace strings except in quotes, including the quotes in python

Tags: python, replace, split, lisp

I making a lisp dialect and I have a function `compute`, which turns for example `(+ 1 2 (- 2 1))` to `('+', '1', '2', ('-', '2', '1'))`.

Here is my current implementation.

```py
import shlex

def compute(expr):
    expr = expr.replace('(', '( ').replace(')', ' )')
    expr = shlex.split(expr)

    new = ''
    for index, i in enumerate(expr):
        if   i == '(': new += i
        elif i == ')': new += i
        elif (not(len(expr) == 1 or len(expr) == 0)) and expr[index+1] == ')':
            new += ('"' + i + '"')
        else:
            new += ('"' + i + '",')
    
    expr = eval(new)
    return expr
```

This works for all expressions, except the ones using strings.

1. `(` and `)` will turn to `(`  and  `)` even in strings
2. As you can see. I'm using `shlex` to not split spaces inside strings, but I want it so that the quotes will be included. So `(println "Hello, world!")` shall turn to `('println', '"Hello, world!"')` and not `('println', 'Hello, world!')`.
3. `\"` completely breaks everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `poxis=False` flag in the `shlex.split()` call, otherwise it get rid of the double quotes:

```
shlex.split(expr)
['(', 'println', 'Hello, world!', ')']
```

Where as:

```
shlex.split(expr, posix=False)
['(', 'println', '"Hello, world!"', ')']
```

**However**, this doesn't solve the issue entirely. You're going to have to modify your code that appends `"` to `i` to this:

```
new = ''
for index, i in enumerate(expr):
    if   i == '(': new += i
    elif i == ')': new += i
    elif (not(len(expr) == 1 or len(expr) == 0)) and expr[index+1] == ')':
        if i[0] == "\"" and i[-1] == "\"": # Check if i starts/ends with "
            new += ('\'' + i + '\'') # Append single quote
        else:
            new += ('"' + i + '"') # Append double quote
    else:
        new += ('"' + i + '",')
```

Now with all the changes in place, `print(compute('(println "Hello, world!")'))` returns:

```
('println', '"Hello, world!"')
```

**Note**: `compute("(+ 1 2 (- 2 1))")` still works as intended.

Comment: thanks, but problems 1 and 3 are still not fixed. `"(A)"` still turns to `( A )` and `\"` still doesn't work as well!

Comment: What is `"(A)"` supposed to return? Because it currently returns `A` **not** `( A )`. What is the scenario that `\"` would be used in?

Comment: I'm talking about `compute('"(A)"')`

Comment: Ok, what is `compute('"(A)"')` supposed to return?

Comment: it's supposed to output `(A)` to standard out, but it outputs `( A )`

Comment: That's because of this statement: `expr = expr.replace('(', '( ').replace(')', ' )')`. What would be expected of this: `compute('"(+ 1 2 (- 2 1))"')`?

Comment: I know. My problem is that I don't know how to not replace it, if it's in quotes